# Azure Policy issue

Tags: json, azure, policy

I have created the policy so that no one can deploy private DNS zone locally as it is being managed centrally. However I need to add exception that users can deploy private DNS zone for some resources locally like aks and postgres flexible server but not not for any other resource like postgres single server and all. Please guide how to achieve

Comment: Goto Azure portal -> select all services -> search for policy -> select Compliance ->select assign policy [image1](https://i.imgur.com/H3Bxytb.png) -> [image2](https://i.imgur.com/ff06Afg.png)->[image3](https://i.imgur.com/GTxWv5o.png)->[image4](https://i.imgur.com/CxYpYj0.png)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, we cannot create a policy for a Service. But you can create a policy for particular resource

please follow the below steps to create a policy for resource

1. Go to Azure portal
2. Select all as shown in below picture
3. search for **policy**

[image]

5. After the above step select **Compliance** and select **assign policy** as shown in below picture

[image]

6. After opening the page, you will find **scope** and select **subscription** and select the **resource Group** it is used to select the particular resource that you want to deploy DNS server in the below steps then click on **select** as shown in below picture

[image]

7. In the next step **Exclusions** and we can select multiple resource and the click on **Add Selected Scope** as shown in below picture

[image]

8. In the policy Definition select type Custom and select **DNSResloverNetworkPrivateGroup** and click on select

[image]
After that click on **review & create** it will create a custom Azure policy to deploy DNS in selected Resource